# How can I prevent a certain piece of code from running when my player reaches a specific score for a certain time?

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer, game-engine, game-development, ienumerator

I'm currently developing a game in Unity and I have a problem. When my player reaches a certain score, in this case, the score of 5 I change the way the obstacles encounter behave. However, for some reason on certain specific occasions when the player reaches the score of 5, I'm assuming when the score of 5 is reached at the exact same time as when the obstacles are being spawned the Obstacles spawn according to the the behaviour required before the score reached 5 but move according to the behaviour required after the score reached 5 instantly as the score of 5 is reached. This shouldn't happen. As the score of 5 is reached the game should keep the behaviour of the obstacles the same as if the score was still smaller than 5 for a second and then switch.

I've already tried to using a coroutine to solve this issue as shown in the code below, however this obviously doesn't work unless I find a way to put the entire class into the coroutine, which will be very messy. I've also tried to suspend the spawning of the obstacles for a second while the score increments from 4 to 5 using a coroutine in the class responsible for spawning the obstacles. However this didn't work

This is the class responsible for the movement of the obstacles:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InteractControl : MonoBehaviour, IPooledObject
{

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    GameObject target;
    Vector3 directionToTarget;
    public static int LevelStart = 0;
    //public GameObject[] Balls;
    Renderer m_Renderer;
    public static float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public static bool isSlowMotion = true;

    public void OnObjectSpawn()
    {
        if (ScoreScript.scoreValue > 4 && isSlowMotion) 
        {
          
            moveSpeed = 10f;
        }

        target = GameObject.FindWithTag("White Ball");
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        MoveInteract(moveSpeed); 
    }

    void MoveInteract(float moveSpeed) 
    {

        if (target != null)
        {
            if (ScoreScript.scoreValue > 4 && ScoreScript.scoreValue < 11 && BallSpawnerControl.LevelTrans > 1) 
            {



                directionToTarget = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(directionToTarget.x * moveSpeed,
                                            directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);

            }
            else if (ScoreScript.scoreValue < 4)
            {
                directionToTarget = new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            GameObject.FindWithTag("ColouredBall Highress").SetActive(false);
        }


    }

    void Update() 
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            if (ScoreScript.scoreValue > 10) //Determine when RedBall goes from going down in a straight line to following white ball
            {



                directionToTarget = (target.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(directionToTarget.x * moveSpeed,
                                            directionToTarget.y * moveSpeed);

            }

        }
        
    }
}
```

This is the class responsible for the spawning of the obstacles:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

/* 
 * ObjectPooler.Instance.SpawnFromPool("Ball", Posi, Quaternion.identity );
 * ObjectPooler.Instance.SpawnFromPool("Star", Posi, Quaternion.identity );
 */

public class BallSpawnerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool spawnAllowed;
    public static int TimerOn = 1;

    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    // public GameObject[] interact;

    int randomSpawnPoint, Interact;
    int index = 1;
    ObjectPooler objectPooler;
    public static int LevelTrans = 1;

    // Use this for initialization
    public void Start()
    {
        objectPooler = ObjectPooler.Instance;
        spawnAllowed = true;
        InvokeRepeating("SpawnAInteract", 0f, 1f);
    }

    void SpawnAInteract()
    {
        // Change this if statement to only run 1 second after the transition to level 2 has been initiated
        if (spawnAllowed) 
        {
            if(ScoreScript.scoreValue > 4 && LevelTrans == 1)
            {
                StartCoroutine(LevelTransition());
            }

            else
            {
                if (index % 5 != 0)
                {
                    randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
                    Interact = 1;

                    // var i = Instantiate(interact[Interact], spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.identity);
                    objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Ball", spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.identity);

                    //randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
                    index++;
                }
                /*if (index % 5 != 0)
                {
                    randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

                    objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Clock", spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.identity);

                } */
                else
                {
                    randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
                    Interact = 0;
                    //  var i = Instantiate(interact[Interact], spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.identity);
                    objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Star", spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.identity);

                    //if (TimerOn == 1)
                    //{
                    randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

                    objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Clock", spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.identity);

                    randomSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

                    objectPooler.SpawnFromPool("Heart", spawnPoints[randomSpawnPoint].position, Quaternion.identity);
                    //    TimerOn++;
                    // }
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator LevelTransition()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        LevelTrans++;
        Debug.Log( "Level Trans :" + LevelTrans);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

This is the interface from which OnObjectspawn derives from:

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public interface IPooledObject
{
    void OnObjectSpawn();
}
```

Comment: Could you limit your code a bit to the neccessary? I don't fully understand how your scripts interact ... where is `OnObjectSpawn` called? Am I right that you want a simple timer so after reaching 5 points it waits a second and then you change some behavior? What about using a bool flag and wait 1 second before activating it?

Comment: I just added the code for the interface that OnObjectspawn derives from. Yes that's what I want to do, I don't know exectly what you mean by a bool flag. But if I'm guessing I already tried something similar when I created an coroutine where I wait for 1 second before changing the value of the integer to something else. However when I tried this for some reason it couldn't acces the new value of the integer set inside the coroutine after the WaitForSeconds(1f); I'm assumed the same would happen if I used a bool instead of an integer incrementation so I didnt try it. Unless I'm wrong

Comment: well somehow both of your classes have their own `private int LevelTrans;` and both have their individual Coroutine for incrementing it ... that doesn't seem right. You should maybe rather make it pubic or even public static in `BallSpawnerControl`. Later you are using none of both values in any conditions for your movement .. so rather check for `if (BallSpawnerControl.LevelTrans > 1` e.g.

Comment: Ok, I will try to implement this and get back to you, thanks man

Comment: @derHugo I just changed the code to reflect the advice you gave in your comments. I made Leveltrans a public static int in the ballspawnercontrol class and I added a condition to my if statement where BallSpawnerControl.LevelTrans > 1 needs to be true in order for  directionToTarget = target.transform.position - transform.position. However now instead of the balls that spawn sometimes moving according to the behaviour required for a score of 5 or more. They spawn byt don't move and then later move again when the code in the update method gets activated. Do you possibly know why this could be?